# Sorting a hash map that contains ArrayList of objects based on the count

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have an array of strings that contains first and last name, age, email, gender, city, and state. I should use ArrayList and hash maps to count the number of people who live in each state and print them in ascending order. Here is what I have so far:

I used an ArrayList to create and put objects in it. In my hash map, I need to have a key and array lists for each state that would contain users who live there

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainPart1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<User> listOfUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<User>> hmap = new HashMap<>();

    for (String str : Data.users) {
        String[] userData = str.split(",");
        User newUser = new User(userData[0], userData[1], Integer.parseInt(userData[2]), userData[3], userData[4], userData[5], userData[6]);
        listOfUsers.add(newUser);
    }

    for (String str : Data.otherUsers) {
        String[] userData = str.split(",");
        User newUser = new User(userData[0], userData[1], Integer.parseInt(userData[2]), userData[3], userData[4], userData[5], userData[6]);
        listOfUsers.add(newUser);
    }

    ArrayList<User> list;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfUsers.size(); i++) {
        String key = listOfUsers.get(i).getState();
        if (hmap.containsKey(key)) {
            list = hmap.get(listOfUsers.get(i).getState());
        }

        else {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        list.add(listOfUsers.get(i));
        hmap.put(key, list);


    }

    System.out.println("State:       Count:");

    for (String key : hmap.keySet()) {
        System.out.print(key + "\t\t\t ");
        System.out.println(hmap.get(key).size());
    }

}
```

}

public class User {

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
private String email;
private String gender;
private String city;
private String state;

public User(String firstName, String lastName, int age, String email, String gender, String city, String state) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.email = email;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstName + "," + lastName + "," + age + "," + email + "," + gender + "," + city + "," + state;
}
```

}

I was able to put the objects into the hash map using the array list but I cannot make it work in the ascending order

Comment: `HashMap` is unordered. If you need it ordered by key, use a `TreeMap`.

Comment: In this assignment, I'm not allowed to use a TreeMap but I can also use HashSet. Idk how it might help though

Comment: So copy the key set to a list and sort it.

Comment: Could you please provide some code on how to do it?

Comment: Wait, do you want to sort by the key or the value?

Comment: I need to sort it by the number of people who live in each state, so it's not the key, it is ArrayList.size() of each ArrayList in the hash map

Comment: To sort the values by size: `List<List<User>> groupsSorted = hmap.values().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(List::size)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: listOfUsers.sort((a, b) -> ((User) a).getState().compareTo(((User) b).getState()));